# How to add menu to a Component Class?

Tags: c#, .net, menu

I've just created a solution and added a 'Component Class' to it.

**All I need is to add a `menu` to `Component Class` when it is in the `componentbar` of a win-form, like the `ImageList` component of .NET.**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Some code relevant to your question will help others understand the question.

Comment: Thanks James, but i didn't typed any code in my project, i've just created a solution and added a 'Component Class'. just this. How can i provide more clarification about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the little tiny arrow that appears on the ImageList component when you select it and you see a list of options.  That requires a custom ComponentDesigner.

Make references to:

```
System.Components.Design
System.Design
System.Windows.Forms.Design
```

Here is a simple little component example:

```
[Designer(typeof(TestComponentDesigner))]
public class TestComponent : Component {

  public class TestComponentDesigner : ComponentDesigner {
    private DesignerVerbCollection verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component) {
      base.Initialize(component);
      verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Say Hello", new EventHandler(SayHello)));
    }

    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs {
      get {
        return verbs;
      }
    }

    private void SayHello(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

[image]

For more information, see [Writing Custom Designers for .NET Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973820.aspx)